# Microservice inside a container is using mavenCli but target folder is not being generateed

Tags: java, docker, microservices, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I'm having a microservice inside of a docker container. This microservice is based on open-api-generator maven plugin in order to generate child projects based on mustache templates and an archetype.

I'm using maven to package the project and create the container. This is my docker file

```
FROM --platform=linux/arm64 maven:3.8.3-openjdk-17 as build
ENV TIME_ZONE America/Guayaquil
ENV TZ=$TIME_ZONE
ENV JAVA_OPTS "-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1250m -Xms256m - 
Dmaven.artifact.threads=10"
WORKDIR /app
RUN mkdir /app/archetype
RUN mkdir /app/archetype/src
ADD archetype/src/ /app/archetype/src/
ADD archetype/*.xml /app/archetype/
ADD archetype/*.json /app/archetype/
ADD archetype/*.md /app/archetype
RUN mkdir /app/openapi
RUN mkdir /app/openapi/templates
ADD openapi/templates/* /app/openapi/templates/
RUN mkdir /app/base

COPY ./base/. /app/base
RUN mkdir /app/devops
RUN mkdir /app/domain
COPY /pom.xml /app/pom.xml
COPY /openapi.yml /app/openapi.yml
COPY /src /app/src

RUN mvn -f /app/pom.xml clean package -Dmaven.artifact.threads=20 -e -X

EXPOSE 9010
ENTRYPOINT exec java -jar /app/target/generator-code-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -e java.io.tmpDir=/app
```

Sorry if there is a better way to write docker file, I'm starting to use docker.

Everything works fine. Maven commands excecuted correctly, the jar is generated inside the `target` folder. The project starts correctly (the project has a front-end web in order to upload the open api contract in yml format).

Now the problem begins (by the way, it work correctly in locally with IntelliJ)

Then I fill my web fields, I upload the new openapi.yml contract and the microservice needs to execute the maven commands (clean install) in order to use the open-API-generator maven plugin and generate the classes. I'm using mavenCli in order to execute maven commands inside of my microservice.

The child project is generated BUT is using the files inside of `target` folder created when the container was built. When the clean install commands are executed it supposed to replace the `target` folder when the new files but nothing is happend.

No errors, warnings. I saw the container files and the target folder was not updated.

I hope I can explained myself correctly.

If there's any way or any configure that I need to perform in order to set the target folder correctly?

This is my POM.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.peigo.ec.generator</groupId>
  <artifactId>peigo-generator-code</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>Generator</name>
  <description>Project Generator Peigo</description>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <openapi-generator.version>4.2.3</openapi-generator.version>
    <cloud-client.version>2.2.5.RELEASE</cloud-client.version>
    <base.package>com.peigo.generator</base.package>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <openapi.source.directory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/openapi</openapi.source.directory>
    

    <maven-failsafe-plugin.version>2.22.2</maven-failsafe-plugin.version>
    <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.22.2</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    ...
    ...
    ...
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>


      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <encoding default-value="UTF-8">UTF-8</encoding>
          <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=${project.build.sourceEncoding}</argLine>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <!-- Used for integration tests -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-failsafe-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <encoding default-value="UTF-8">UTF-8</encoding>
          <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=${project.build.sourceEncoding} -Djava.io.tmpdir=${project.build.directory}</argLine>
          <skipTests>true</skipTests>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>${java.version}</source>
          <target>${java.version}</target>
          <release>${java.version}</release>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
        <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>generate</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <!-- This section includes the "global" configuration options, so called because they apply to all generators. Users generally don't need to care about this detail, except to make sure their configuration information lands in the correct place - <configuration> vs <configOptions>. -->

              <!-- The OpenAPI spec is in a file in this repository called "openapi.yml". It can also be a hyperlink. -->
              <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/openapi.yml</inputSpec>

              <!-- There are many generators available. We are using jaxrs-spec. -->
              <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
              <library>spring-boot</library>
              <!-- APIs are service interfaces or implementations. -->
              <generateApis>true</generateApis>
              <!-- Models are DTOs, generally from the schemas portion of the spec. -->
              <generateModels>true</generateModels>

              <!-- In this example, we're not generating the POM, README, etc. -->
              <generateSupportingFiles>false</generateSupportingFiles>

              <!-- This is the default value, but be explicit so it's clear when we refer to the value elsewhere. -->
              <output>${openapi.source.directory}</output>

              <!-- We are showing off template customization today. The custom templates are stored here. -->
              <templateDirectory>${project.basedir}/openapi/templates</templateDirectory>

              <configOptions>
                <!-- These are the "local" configuration options that apply only to this generator. -->
                <!-- https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/jaxrs-spec -->

                <!-- These are the packages we want our APIs and Models generated in, respectively. -->
                <apiPackage>com.ec.peigo.infrastructure.adapter.input</apiPackage>
                <modelPackage>com.ec.peigo.domain.model</modelPackage>
                <useBeanValidation>true</useBeanValidation>
                <performBeanValidation>true</performBeanValidation>
                <serializableModel>true</serializableModel>
                <skipDefaultInterface>false</skipDefaultInterface>
                <dateLibrary>java17</dateLibrary>
                <useSwaggerAnnotations>true</useSwaggerAnnotations>

                <!-- These values are largely up to you, and depend on your goals and philosophy. This SSCCE should support all permutations of the below. -->

                <!-- I prefer to have interface methods return model objects, not JAX-RS Response objects. I can still generate any response I want by throwing WebApplicationException classes. -->
                <!-- If this is set to true, then all generated service methods will return javax.ws.rs.core.Response objects. -->
                <!-- If this is set to false, then all generated service methods will return their respective model objects. -->
                <returnResponse>false</returnResponse>

                <!-- I prefer to generate interfaces, not implementation. This allows me to make sure that my client and server implementations are in sync. -->
                <!-- If this is set to true, then service interfaces will be generated. -->
                <!-- If this is set to false, then service implementations will be generated. -->
                <interfaceOnly>false</interfaceOnly>

                <!-- This is a useful feature for web frameworks that support the JAX-RS 2.1 feature of implementing asynchronous processing by returning CompletionStage instances. In all cases, generated service methods return either Response or a model object, depending on the above configuration. This configuration option affects all methods. Users cannot choose to make individual methods synchronous versus asynchronous. -->
                <!-- If this is set to true, then all generated service method return types will be changed from T to CompletionStage<T>. -->
                <!-- If this is set to false, then all generate service method return types will be unchanged. -->
                <supportAsync>false</supportAsync>
              </configOptions>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>add-source</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sources>
                <!-- Add the generated source to the project so it gets compiled -->
                <source>${openapi.source.directory}/src/gen/java</source>
              </sources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>


</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be:-

```
ENTRYPOINT exec java -jar /app/app/target/generator-code-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -e java.io.tmpDir=/app
```

jar should be at - /app/app/target

I guess the reason for this should be `WORKDIR /app`

To debug your dockerfile you may add this command at various places

```
RUN ls -lrt
```

what it will do is show the directory content as list

Comment: I'm sorry for my late response. Didn't work. Thanks by the way. I'm still with the issue